# Wordpress functions.php not working

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Trying to include my style sheet via the functions.php file but the styles are failing to show...

```
function theme_styles () {

    wp_enqueue_style('normalize', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/normalize.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style('grid', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/grid.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style('google', '' );
    wp_enqueue_style('main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}
```

I have style.css within the theme folder and a CSS file with a style.css file inside that too but the styles are not showing...

Comment: Are you calling that `theme_styles` function anywhere in your theme?

Comment: Where where would this be included?

Comment: I found what I was missing - thank you for the heads up add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles');

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hey wp_enqueue_scripts is the proper hook to use when enqueuing style sheet or script

Use to enqueue your style sheet

```
function theme_styles () {

    wp_enqueue_style('normalize', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/normalize.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style('grid', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/grid.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style('google', '' );
    wp_enqueue_style('main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles' );
```

Sure it will work good

Answer (score 9):

I ran into a similar problem. After sometime I realized I forgot to add the `wp_head()` hook before the end of the `head` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')` instead of `get_template_directory_uri()`.

Comment: Hasnt changed anything, I feel like I am missing something here but not too sure what...